# ASP.NET MVC 5 Bundling and minification Javascript ES6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ecmascript-6, bundling-and-minification

Minification fails when I try to use Ecmascript-6 features in my app.

If i try to use an arrow function:

```js
$.get('/clients/all').done(response => {
  // Do something with the response
})
```

I get the following error:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(8,45-46): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: >
(36,6-7): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: )
(37,1-2): run-time error JS1002: Syntax error: }
 */
```

And so on with other ES6 features.

Do you know an ItemTransform for ES6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still there is no .NET bundling package for ES6+.

> But **as a workaround** you can use: *babeljs.io > Try It Out > Presets: ES2015*.

The following code:

```
var gridNames = Enumerable.From(verifiedKeys).Select(x => `demo_${x}`).ToArray();
```

Will be translated into:

```
var gridNames = Enumerable.From(verifiedKeys).Select(function (x) {
  return "demo_" + x;
}).ToArray();
```

**Link:** https://babeljs.io/repl and check: `Presets > ES2015`.